# Solve $2^m=7n^2+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, algebraic-number-theory

Solve $2^m=7n^2+1$ with $(m,n)\in \mathbb{N}^2$

Here is what I did:
First try, I have seen first that the obvious solutions are $n=1$ and $m=3$ , and $n=3$ and $m=6$, then I proved by simple congruences that $m$ must be divisible by $3$ so $m=3k$, If we add $27$ to the equation we will have $2^{3k}+3^3=7(n^2+2^2)$, but unfortunately I tried to do something with Legendre symbol or the multiplicative order but I found nothing interesting.

Second try,I let $n=2k+1$ then I worked in $\mathbb{Z}\left[ \frac{-1+\sqrt{-7}}{2} \right] $ and the equation becomes $7\times 2^{m-2}=\left( 7k+4+\frac{-1+\sqrt{-7}}{2} \right) \left( 7k+3-\frac{-1+\sqrt{-7}}{2} \right) $ but I didn't find something interesting because the two factors are not coprime.

Comment: modular arithmetic ...

Comment: Either $m=6$ or $m$ is a power of $3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** The only solutions are $(m,n)=(6,3)$ and $(m,n)=(3,1)$.

This answer is rather long and has been split in two parts. In part one, we show that, with the exception of $(6,3)$ we must have $m$ a power of $3$ for all solutions $(m,n)$.

In part $2$, we show that $(r,n)=(1,1)$ is the only solution to
$$2^{3^r}=7n^2+1.$$

## Part 1

Let $(m,n)$ be any solution to the equation
$$2^m=7n^2+1.$$
First, suppose that $m$ is even. Write $m=2k$ and note that the equation is equivalent with
$$(2^k+1)(2^k-1)=7n^2.$$
Since $2^k+1$ and $2^k-1$ are both odd and just two apart, they're coprime. This means that one of these factors is a square and the other is seven times a square. Note that $2^k+1$ is congruent to one of $2$, $3$ and $5$ modulo $7$. Therefore, it must be a square. Write $2^k+1=l^2$, then
$$2^k = (l+1)(l-1),$$
so both $l-1$ and $l+1$ are powers of $2$. Clearly, the only solution is $k=l=3$, which corresponds to the solution $(m,n)=(6,3)$ of the original equation.

---

Otherwise, $m$ is odd. Write $m=3^rs$ with $s$ odd and not divisible by $3$. Note that
$$7n^2=2^{3^rs}-1=(2^s-1)\sum_{i=0}^{3^r-1}2^{si}.$$
Let $p$ be any prime dividing $2^s-1$. We have $2^{si}\equiv 1\pmod p$ for all $i$, meaning that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{3^r-1}2^{si}\equiv 3^r\pmod p.$$
Because $s$ is odd, $p\neq 3$. We conclude that $2^s-1$ and $\prod_{i=0}^{3^r-1}2^{si}$ are coprime. Therefore, $2^s-1$ is either a square or seven times a square. Since $3\nmid s$, it cannot not be the latter. Because $2^s-1$ is an odd square, it must be congruent to $1$ modulo $8$, so $s<3$. Because $s$ is odd, it must be $1$ and $m=3^r$.

## Part 2

The key result here is:

**Lemma:** Let $a\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$ be given with $a\pmod 3\in \{0,2\}$. All elements of the sequence
$$\left\{1+a^{2\cdot 3^n}+a^{3^n}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}}$$
are pairwise coprime.

**Proof:** Let $k,l$ be non-negative integers, $k>l$. We have the polynomial identities
$$
\begin{align*}
X^{3^k}-1 &= \left(X^{3^{l+1}}-1\right)\sum_{i=0}^{3^{k-l-1}-1}X^{3^{l+1}i}\\
&= \left(1+X^{2\cdot 3^l}+X^{3^l}\right)\left(X^{3^l}-1\right)\sum_{i=0}^{3^{k-l-1}-1}X^{3^{l+1}i}
\end{align*}
$$
and
$$1+X^{2\cdot 3^k}+X^{3^k}=X^{3^k}\left(X^{3^k}+1\right)+1.$$
It follows that
$$1+X^{2\cdot 3^k}+X^{3^k}=q\left(1+X^{2\cdot 3^l}+X^{3^l}\right)+3,$$
where
$$q=\left(1+X^{2\cdot 3^l}+X^{3^l}\right)(X^{3^l}-1)^2\left[\sum_{i=0}^{3^{k-l-1}-1}X^{3^{l+1}i}\right]^2+3(X^{3^l}-1)\sum_{i=0}^{3^{k-l-1}-1}X^{3^{l+1}i}$$
has integer coefficients. Evaluating in $a$ yields
$$1+a^{2\cdot 3^{k}}+a^{3^k}=q(a)\left(1+a^{2\cdot 3^l}+a^{3^l}\right)+3,$$
where $q(a)$ is an integer. By Fermat's little theorem,
$$1+a^{2\cdot 3^{k}}+a^{3^k}\equiv 1+a^{2\cdot 3^{l}}+a^{3^l}\equiv 2a+1\not\equiv 0\pmod 3.$$
Hence, $1+a^{2\cdot 3^k}+a^{3^k}$ and $1+a^{2\cdot 3^l}+a^{3^l}$ are coprime. Q.E.D.

---

Consider any solution $(r,n)$ to
$$2^{3^r}=7n^2+1.$$
Note that this is equivalent with
$$
\begin{align*}
7n^2 &= 2^{3^r}-1\\ 
&= \prod_{i=0}^{r-1}\frac{2^{3^{i+1}}-1}{2^{3^i}-1}\\
&= \prod_{i=0}^{r-1}\left(1+2^{2\cdot 3^i}+2^{3^i}\right)\\
&= 7\prod_{i=1}^{r-1}\left(1+2^{2\cdot 3^i}+2^{3^i}\right).
\end{align*}
$$
By the lemma, the factors in the final product must be pairwise coprime, so they must be squares. However, the factor given by $i=1$ is
$$1+2^{2\cdot 3}+2^3=1+64+8=73,$$
which isn't a square. Therefore, $r\le 1$. We find that $(r,n)=(1,1)$ is the only solution.

Comment: An interesting answer, but you might want to fix some errors (typos). (1) It seems that $\prod_{i=0}^{3^r-1}2^{si}$ has to be $\sum_{i=0}^{3^r-1}2^{si}$. (2) It seems that $l$ has to be $k$ in $1+X^{2\cdot 3^k}+X^{3^l}=X^{3^k}\left(X^{3^k}+1\right)+1$. (3) It seems that $1+X^{2\cdot 3^k}+X^{3^k}=q\left(1+X^{2\cdot 3^l}+X^{3^l}\right)+3$ does not hold. For $(X,k,l)=(2,1,0)$, $LHS=73$ but $RHS=59$.

Comment: Please see my answer for a simpler handling of the odd case. (Ironically, I had trouble with the even case, until I saw from your answer how easy it was.)

Comment: @mathlove I corrected (1) and (2). As for (3), it seems to me that the LHS is 73 and the RHS is 7q+3, which is correct

Comment: It seems that your $q$ is wrong. I got $q=8$ instead of $10$. So, $RHS=59$, not $73$.

Comment: @mathlove You're right. I believe it's correct now

Comment: "Note that $2^k+1$ is congruent to one of 2, 3 and 5 modulo 7. Therefore, it must be a square."  I am lost.  How are numbers having these residues guaranteed square when 3 and 5 are not even quadratic residues?

Comment: Now I see.  I filled in a step to untangle the quadratic residue issue.

Comment: It seems that your $q$ is still wrong. For $(X,k,l)=(2,1,0)$, your $q$ equals $9$. So, $RHS=66$, not $73$.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi : I think that what Mastrem is saying is as follows : "$2^k+1$ is either a square or seven times a square. Since $2^k+1\not\equiv 0\pmod 7$, $2^k+1$ is not seven times a square. Hence, $2^k+1$ is a square."

Comment: I deleted a sentence and corrected $q$. I hope you don't mind my edit.

Answer (score 2):

If $2^m=7n^2+1$ with $m=3k$, as the OP found must be the case (since $2^m\equiv1$ mod $7$), we have

$$7n^2=2^{3k}-1=(2^k-1)(2^{2k}+2^k+1)$$

Now for $k\ge1$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\gcd(2^k-1,2^{2k}+2^k+1)
&=\gcd(2^k-1,2^{2k}+2^{k+1})\\
&=\gcd(2^k-1,2^{k+1}(2^{k-1}+1))\\
&=\gcd(2^k-1,2^{k-1}+1)\\
&=\gcd(2^k+2^{k-1},2^{k-1}+1)\\
&=\gcd(3\cdot2^{k-1},2^{k-1}+1)\\
&=\gcd(3,2^{k-1}+1)\\
&=\begin{cases}
3\quad\text{if $k$ is even}\\
1\quad\text{if $k$ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

If $k$ is even, we proceed as in Mastrem's answer: $k=2h$ implies $7n^2=2^{6h}-1=(2^{3h}-1)(2^{3h}+1)$ with $\gcd(2^{3h}-1,2^{3h}+1)=1$ and $7\mid(2^{3h}-1)$, so $2^{3h}+1$ must be a square, but $2^{3h}+1=N^2$ implies $2^{3h}=(N-1)(N+1)$, which holds only for $N=3$, corresponding to the known solution with $m=6$.

If $k$ is odd, then we must have $7$ divide one of the factors in $(2^k-1)(2^{2k}+2^k+1)$ and the other factor be a square. If $k\ge3$, $2^k-1\equiv-1$ mod $8$, which is not a square, so we must have $7\mid2^k-1$, which implies $k=3h$ (with $h$ odd, but that's no longer important), from which it follows that $2^{6h}+2^{3h}+1$ is a square. But $2^{6h}+2^{3h}+1\equiv1+1+1\equiv3$ mod $7$, which is not a square. So the case of odd $k$ leaves only $k=1$, corresponding to the other known solution, $m=3$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT

$2^m\equiv 1$ mod $7$ and so $m=3k$. For $n>0$, we now have
$$2^k-1=au^2, 2^{2k}+2^k+1=bv^2$$
where either $\{a,b\}=\{1,7\}$ or $\{a,b\}=\{3,21\}.$

Each of the four possibilities gives an elliptic curve $$bv^2=3+3au^2+a^2u^4.$$

Of these, the case $a=7,b=1$ is impossible modulo $7$.